# How to get the last words of the line in log?

Tags: bash, logs, variable, tail, output

I have the following code:

```
#! /bin/sh

tail -f /var/log/omxlog | stdbuf -o0 grep player_new | while read i
do
       omxd S
done
```

which outputs the playlist of videos in the following format (in real time):

```
...
Playing 33/75 /myfolder/F01_Ship_111.mp4
Playing 0/22 /myfolder/F02_Car_101.mp4
Playing 11/32 /myfolder/F03_Animal_001.mp4
Playing 23/84 /myfolder/F04_Book_000.mp4
...
```

Now I want to save the name of the current video that is being played in several variables, like:

```
x1 = F01_Ship_111.mp4
x2 = F01_Ship_111
x3 = F01
x4 = Ship
x5 = 111
x6 = mp4
```

So, how can I do this !?

Comment: where do you use your i variable ?

Comment: `IFS=[_.] read -a x <<<"F01_Ship_111.mp4"` will put each name into *x*-array which you can access via `${x[0…3]}`

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
Values=$(omxd S | awk -F/ '{print $NF}')
x1="${Values}"
x2="${Values%.*}"
x3="${Values%%.*}"
x4=$(echo ${Values} | cut -d_ -f2)
x5=$(echo ${x2} | cut -d_ -f2)
x6=${Values##*.}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kamaraj for your answer. But the output for some of these variables are incorrect: V03_Arch_333.mp4 , V03_Arch_333 , V03_Arch_333 , Arch , Arch , mp4

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged bash, I'll use its `[[ ... ]]` [Conditional Construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs):

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -f /var/log/omxlog | stdbuf -o0 grep player_new | while read i
do
  [[ $i =~ .*/([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^.]+).(.+)$ ]] && {
  x1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_${BASH_REMATCH[2]}_${BASH_REMATCH[3]}.${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
  x2=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_${BASH_REMATCH[2]}_${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
  x3=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  x4=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  x5=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
  x6=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
  }
  omxd S
done
```